# How to change the beamer font into Times New Roman?

Tags: beamer, fonts

I want to change the beamer font into Times New Roman.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usecolortheme[named=black]{structure}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  
  This is a sample frame.
  
  Math equation: $E = mc^2$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But the \setmainfont{Times New Roman} does not work.

Comment: Beamer uses sans fonts per default. So, you should try `\setsansfont{Times New Roman}`.